# how to place lable vertically in iphone app to give the name of bar line

Tags: iphone, ipad, uilabel

[image]

I want to show the UILabel verticall place like the normal graph label have 
like if 
100
200
300
400
then Calculate Graph should be vertical aligned. 
Image is also attached.I want to set label as Risk as shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate your label as much you want

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2*3); // 90 degress
```

Comment: it is coming but text is inverse how to set this

Comment: I change the angle to 270 but you can also use (-M_PI_2)

Comment: You just play with by changing degree up to getting right angle

Answer (score 0):

```
 CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees)
{
 return degrees * M_PI / 180;
};

 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-DegreesToRadians(90));
 label.transform = transform;
```